# How to add free and not free video in WordPress and WooCommerce theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my code. I want to display the video watch link and video download link if the video is free. If the video is not free, I don't want to display the links. When the course is fully purchased, I want to display the video watch link and video download link. By the way, I am using WordPress and WooCommerce. Currently, my code doesn't display the links for free and non-free videos until the course is fully purchased.

My meta box code:

```
  $courses_group_sessions = $courses_metaboxes->add_field( array(
        'id'          => $perfix.'course_sessions_group',
        'type'        => 'group',
        'description' => __( 'Please add the sections or chapters of the lesson here.', $textdomain ),
        'options'     => array(
            'group_title'       => __( 'Main topics', $textdomain ),
            'add_button'        => __( 'Add topic', $textdomain ),
            'remove_button'     => __( 'Delete topic ', $textdomain ),
            'sortable'          => true,
        ),
    ) );

    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field( $courses_group_sessions, array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Topic title', $textdomain ),
        'id'   => $perfix . 'part_title',
        'type' => 'text',
    ) );
    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_sessions, array(
        'name'    => __('Is Free', $textdomain),
        'id'      => $perfix . 'is_free_lessons',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'repeatable' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'free'     => __('Free', $textdomain),
            'not_free' => __('Not Free', $textdomain),
        ),
        'text' => array(
            'add_row_text' => 'Add video status',
        ),
    ));
    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_sessions, array(
        'name' => __('Sessions', $textdomain),
        'id' => $perfix . 'menu_lessons',
        'type' => 'text',
        'repeatable' => true,
        'text' => array(
            'add_row_text' => 'Add sessions',
        ),
        'desc' => __('add the titles of the sessions', $textdomain),
    ));
    
    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_sessions, array(
        'name' => __('Download links', $textdomain),
        'id' => $perfix . 'link_lessons',
        'type' => 'text_url',
        'repeatable' => true,
        'text' => array(
            'add_row_text' => 'Add link',
        ),
        'desc' => __('Important note: Please add the session links in the order specified in the above section. This means that if you enter a link for, lets say, session number 3, it will be considered for the title of session number 3', $textdomain),
    ));
    
    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_sessions, array(
        'name' => __('Video times', $textdomain),
        'id' => $perfix . 'duration_time_lessons',
        'type' => 'text_small',
        'repeatable' => true,
        'text' => array(
            'add_row_text' => 'Add video times',
        ),
        'desc' => __('Important note: Please add the video durations in the order specified in the above section. This means that if you set the duration for video number 3, it will be set for the title of video number 3', $textdomain),
    ));
```

my course content code:

```
<?php
   global $product;
   $prefix = 'paradox_';
   $course_sessions_group = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $prefix . 'course_sessions_group', 
    true);
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ($course_sessions_group) :
    ?>
<div id="course_sessions" class="course_sessions rcontent_course_box dot">
    <h4 class="guranty">Course sessions</h4>
    <?php
    $sec_counter = 1;
    foreach ($course_sessions_group as $course_sessions) :
        ?>
        <!--Start course Section -->
        <div class="rsession_item accordion_item">
            <div class="click_accordion">
                <div class="head_inner_accordion sec_head">
                    <span class="title_icon">
                        <span class="sec_title">Section <?php echo esc_html($sec_counter); ?></span>
                        <h3 class="accordion_items_title"><?php echo esc_html($course_sessions['paradox_part_title']); ?></h3>
                    </span>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion_content box_content">
                <?php
                $myindex = 0;
                $counter = 1;
                $new_course_sessions = $course_sessions;
                foreach ($course_sessions['paradox_menu_lessons'] as $course_sessions_info) :
                    $is_free = isset($course_sessions['paradox_is_free_lessons'][$myindex]) ? $course_sessions['paradox_is_free_lessons'][$myindex] : '';
                    $buy_session_link = $new_course_sessions['paradox_link_lessons'][$myindex];
                    $is_purchased = true;

                    if (!$is_free) {
                        // بررسی خرید ویدئو توسط کاربر
                        $product_id = $new_course_sessions['paradox_product_id_lessons'][$myindex];
                        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                        if ($product) {
                            $is_purchased = wc_customer_bought_product($current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id());
                        }
                    }

                    if ($is_free && $is_purchased) {
                        // ویدئو رایگان است و خریداری شده است
                        ?>
                        <!--Start course sessions -->
                        <div class="course_sessions_item">
                            <div class="click_accordion">
                                <div class="head_inner_accordion">
                                    <span class="title_icon">
                                        <span class="sec_number"><?php echo esc_html($counter); ?></span>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($buy_session_link); ?>">
                                            <h3 class="accordion_items_title"><?php echo esc_html($new_course_sessions['paradox_menu_lessons'][$myindex]); ?></h3>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="rcourse_time"><?php echo esc_html($new_course_sessions['paradox_duration_time_lessons'][$myindex]); ?>
                                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--End course sessions -->
                        <?php
                        $counter++;
                    }

                    $myindex++;
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End course Section -->
        <?php
        $sec_counter++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
<?php
```

endif;
?>